# Want to put data included in JSON into a hyperlink in a D3 tree diagram

Tags: javascript, d3.js, tree

I'm trying to use the D3 collapsable tree diagram form Rob Schmuecker’s Block 7880033 to visualise a data structure and then choose a web form via a hyperlink embedded in a node.

After a lot of trial and error, I have managed to get a static hyperlink ie: all the nodes in the diagram take me to the same place on click.

I want to extract an element from the JSON input file to populate the link dynamically for each node as the diagram loads.

I have ammended the JSON to include a field called tid for each node, Please can someone tell me how to access that field and use to in the hyperlink.

The Json looks like the original json except I have renamed the "size" element as "tid". This is a sample, the whole file goes on a bit.

The JSON is loaded into an array like this...

```
{"name":" Test top level"," tid":" 1","children": [{ "name":" another test zone"," tid":" 1","children": [{ "name":" First Index"," tid":" 1"},{"name":" The Cats Index"," tid":" 3"},{"name":" The Dogs Index"," tid":" 4"},{"name":" A special Index edited"," tid":" 5"}]}]}
```

The data all gets put in an array like this...

```
{name: " Test top level", " tid": " 1", children: Array(1)}
" tid": " 1"
children: Array(1)
0:
" tid": " 1"
children: Array(4)
0: {name: " A special Index edited", " tid": " 5", parent: {…}, depth: 2, x: 17.5, …}
1: {name: " First Index", " tid": " 1", parent: {…}, depth: 2, x: 52.5, …}
2: {name: " The Cats Index", " tid": " 3", parent: {…}, depth: 2, x: 87.5, …}
3: {name: " The Dogs Index", " tid": " 4", parent: {…}, depth: 2, x: 122.5, …}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
depth: 1
id: 5
name: " another test zone"
parent: {name: " Test top level", " tid": " 1", children: Array(1), x0: 70, y0: 0, …}
x: 70
x0: 70
y: 92
y0: 92
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
depth: 0
id: 6
name: " Test top level"
x: 70
x0: 70
y: 0
y0: 0
__proto__: Object
```

The code segment I am trying to use to write the link is:

```
   node = svgGroup.selectAll("g.node")
        .data(nodes, function(d) {
            return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
        });

    // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
    var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .call(dragListener)
        .attr("class", "node")
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
            return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
        })
        .on('click', click);

    nodeEnter.append("a")
        .attr("xlink:href", "http://en.wikipedia.org?")
        .append("circle")
        .attr('class', 'nodeCircle')
        .attr("r", 0)
        .style("fill", function(d) {
            return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
        });

    nodeEnter.append("text")
        .attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
        })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .attr('class', 'nodeText')
        .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
            return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
        })
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.name;
            return d.tid;
        })
        .style("fill-opacity", 0);

    // phantom node to give us mouseover in a radius around it
    nodeEnter.append("circle")
        .attr('class', 'ghostCircle')
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("opacity", 0.2) // change this to zero to hide the target area
    .style("fill", "red")
        .attr('pointer-events', 'mouseover')
        .on("mouseover", function(node) {
            overCircle(node);
        })
        .on("mouseout", function(node) {
            outCircle(node);
        });
```

I'm just not sure how to access those tid elements and include them into the URL for the node link.

This is hopefully a Javascript beginner problem.

Thanks for looking

Paul

Comment: tag `a` is not a valid svg element. add a click handler to your circle or ghost-circle and read the field with the link address and set the `window.location`. use fill `transparent` for ghost-circle. get the field `tid` the same as you get the field `children`

Comment: *"tag a is not a valid svg element"*... yes, it is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/a

Comment: @Paul Ingram create a bl.ocks with your code, even if it doesn't work. You can fork the bl.ocks you mentioned and edit it with https://blockbuilder.org.

Comment: Thanks for you help folks. It was a coding error on my part. the tid object I wanted to access was defined with a leading space in the name. @GerardoFurtado thanks for the Blocks.org pointer, there is a lot of useful stuff there.